# Show & Hide hidden files on demand in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

A little while ago I discovered that on Ubuntu linux one can [display or conceal hidden files on demand](http://www.zolved.com/synapse/view_content/28276/How_to_show_hidden_files_folders_on_Ubuntu) at run-time by pressing [Ctrl-H]. This is **really** handy. Is there anyway this can be had on windows?

I'm guessing Windows Explorer is not amenable to this, so I'm open to 3rd party file managers provided they're open source, freeware, or cheap (in order of preference).

thanks

Comment: Now don't you wish nautilus was available for Windows? ;P

Comment: Didn't know about this feature. Neat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Install [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Then implement a hot key script by following these instructions:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/keyboard-ninja/keyboard-ninja-toggle-hidden-files-with-a-shortcut-key-in-windows/

Comment: I wish I could give this more than one vote.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [StExBar](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar.html). It is a shell-extension that adds a toolbar to Windows Explorer and among other functions allows quick and easy access to toggling viewing of hidden/system files and folders. You can click the toolbar button as below or press a hotkey (defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). You can also add your own buttons.

[image: Screenshot of StExView toolbar with *Hidden-File-Toggle* button highlighted]

Answer (score 2):

In Total Commander you can add a button to the button bar and bind it to the below command

```
cm_SwitchHidSys
```

This toggles visibility of hidden/system files. Not quite a shortcut key, but a step in the right direction.

Comment: Shaji got the nod for ease of installation and simplicity (it helps that I prefer keyboard to button). It looks like Total Commander is worth exploring for other reasons too. Thanks.